# Does wglMakeCurrent, drawing, and multithreading cause a race?

Tags: multithreading, winapi, opengl

If I have two opengl rendering threads, each of which has a pattern of setting its context, doing drawing at a fixed framerate. Will there be a race?

I am worried that the following will happen:

1. Thread 1 calls wglMakeCurrent
2. Thread 2 calls wglMakeCurrent
3. Thread 2 draws
4. Thread 1 draws

In turn both threads draw on the context of the second thread.

Should I be using locks whenever I set a rendering context, and draw to ensure the operation doesn't interfere with other rendering threads?

Comment: Please refer my answer for more details.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47918078/creating-opengl-structures-in-a-multithreaded-program/47921647#47921647

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as each thread has its own context, you can draw in both threads safely.

Only if you want to share a single context between the threads you have to ensure that the context is current only in a single thread at a time.

The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374387(v=vs.85).aspx) of `wglMakeCurrent()` sets up the rules:

> A thread can have one current rendering context. A process can have multiple rendering contexts by means of multithreading.
>
> A thread must set a current rendering context before calling any OpenGL functions. Otherwise, all OpenGL calls are ignored.
>
> A rendering context can be current to only one thread at a time. You cannot make a rendering context current to multiple threads.
>
> An application can perform multithread drawing by making different rendering contexts current to different threads, supplying each thread with its own rendering context and device context.

Comment: Does thread switching implicitly store/restore rendering context of the thread?

Comment: Oh it does; [The wglMakeCurrent function makes a specified OpenGL rendering context the calling thread's current rendering context."](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374387(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: Take a look at the documentation of `wglMakeCurrent()` at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374387(v=vs.85).aspx 
The remarks sections defines the rules. It is your responsibility to ensure the context is no longer current in one thread before making it current in another thread.

Comment: i notice this pattern is not alone in windows api/c standard library(strtok), used in SetLastError/GetLastError(effect current thread only). I wonder how expensive those threadlocal variables are compared to keeping state in a structure and passing that as an extra argument to them.