# OpenGL create and load VBO information in a different thread than the rendering thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, opengl, glfw

I am going to try to explain the best I can, but this is quite convoluted already.

Given 2 threads Master and slave, I need the master thread to render uninterrupted and the slave thread to do any and ALL VBO loading operations. In other words, the slave thread creates VAO's, VBO's, even textures, and it is the slave thread that calls `glBufferData()` to pass the information into VRAM.

To my understanding, one must create 2 OpenGL contexts that share their data (one per thread) make each current in it's respective thread, and it should now be possible to load the data in one and render it in the other.

I have tried without success to implement this, and my application seems to big for me to simply show the code and expect people to understand what's going on.

If possible I'd like someone with previous experience doing something like this to explain to me a step by step way to achieve this kind of parallelization.

Comment: first part is whether or not two contexts can share resources depends on how you created the contexts. they don't automatically share resources and setting up contexts with shared resources is platform specific. secondly my experience is that drivers are very buggy when in comes to mutlithreading so for example chrome uses just one thread. Even if your driver is not buggy  the spec says in order to see changes in one context in another you're required to call glFinish in one context and then glBindXXX in the other for the modified resource.

Comment: I'd suggest you use just one thread, you can prep data in a different thread but when it's ready use your single graphics thread to upload it. Either that or switch to Vulkan which was designed to allow mutlithreading better

Comment: You're not really benefitting from any parallelization on the GPU's side. For performance, applications usually dedicate a thread to GL operations (thereby avoiding context switches), and any other thread(s) to the application logic.

Comment: Possible duplication. Please see  https://stackoverflow.com/a/47921647/7598582?stw=2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My advice is make all OpenGL calls from one thread. The implicit OpenGL context is thread specific and trying to work around that will require access to a whole buch ofvplatform specific extensions and is likely to be buggy.

Having said that there is nothing to stop you loading the data in VAOs VBOs an textures and pass pointers to the memory to your openGL thread which then make the glBuffer and glTexture calls for your slave thread by proxy.